# How do I split a string on both commas and newlines in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string that can come in with either commas or newlines, based on an input from a textarea. I'm not sure of the syntax to split this string in c#.
Currently I have:

```
string[] splitString = inputString.Split(','); //WORKS
//string[] splitString = inputString.Split(new string[] { ",","\r\n","\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: We cannot help you with "don't work". What did you expect? What happened instead? Can you write a [mcve]?

Comment: `Regex.Split(@"[,\r\n]", str)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Should it be [Regex.Split(string input, string pattern)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @J3soon sorry confused with the arguments order..

Answer (score 8):

Since some text uses `\r` for new line.

You should use the code below and remove the empty entries to make the array cleaner.

```
string[] splitString = inputString.Split(new string[] { ",", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

or using [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (This doesn't remove empty entries.)

```
String[] splitString = Regex.Split(inputString, "[,\r\n]");
```

**Update**

You can also use [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with empty entries removed, thanks to [WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/)'s comment.

The code below removes the empty entries which aren't in the beginning or end of the string.

```
String[] splitString = Regex.Split(inputString, "[,\r\n]+");
```

To eliminate empty entries showing in the beginning or end of the line, use the code below.

```
Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(inputString, "^[,\r\n]+|[,\r\n]+$", ""), "[,\r\n]+");
```

**Regular Expression Language**

If you want more informations about `Regex`, or how it works, you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a quick reference.

Comment: You could modify the `Regex.Split` to not split `CRLF` into empty lines with `String[] splitString = Regex.Split(inputString, "(\r\n|\r|\n|,)");`

Comment: Did you escape the backslashes, or use `@"(\r\n|\r|\n|,)"`. I just copied my regex in there and didn't think about that. Made this [example](https://regex101.com/r/oZ1oR3/1) to illustrate it. `r` and `n` are placeholders for `\r` and `\n` just for clarity.

Comment: It seems like the `Regex.Split` inserts capture groups into the string sequence (or something like that :S). I didn't know that. So change it to `@"(?:\r\n|\r|\n|,)"` and it works :)

Comment: @ClasG Nope, it still fails with multiple `,` or newline character. I tried to use `Regex.Split` and remove the empty entries by myself, but in vain...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107234/discussion-between-j3soon-and-clasg).

Comment: `String[] splitString = Regex.Split(inputString, "[,\r\n]").Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)).ToArray();`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But this seems to double the time spent ignoring the empty entries. I'm wondering how we can use only patterns in `Regex.Split` :)

Comment: @J3soon: I do not think there is a big performance hit here. There will always be empty elements. Try also with `"[,\r\n]+"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It surely works!! Can you please explain why the patterns looks like that? I'm not a expert in `Regex` myself...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I got it! There's a full reference on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If the split pattern is found at the beginning/end of the string, there will be an empty element. To eliminate it, you will need a 2 step S&R: `Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(s, "^[,\r\n]+|[,\r\n]+$", ""), "[,\r\n]+")`. I do not think a regex is necessary here anyway.

Comment: @J3soon I'm not sure what makes you assume empty lines should be removed... That certainly isn't the way I interpret it. Wouldn't the OP have set `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Environment.NewLine into your string array:

```
string[] splitString = inputString.Split(new string[] { ",", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```